# Composer install\update authentication fails

Tags: php, git, composer-php, bitbucket-server

When I'm trying to install dependency from my private repository, I'm getting the following error:

```
> php.exe composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information

  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Failed to clone https://my.stash.repo/scm/lib/my-super-lib.git, could no  
  t read packages from it                                                      

  fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://my.stash.repo/scm/lib/my-super-lib.git/'                                                                   

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]

Process finished with exit code 1 at 10:57:04.
Execution time: 1 996 ms.
```

Relevant `composer.json` part looks as following:

```
   "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "scaytrase/my-super-lib": "1.1"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "https://my.stash.repo/scm/lib/my-super-lib.git"
        }
    ],
```

If I set username and password directly like

```
"url":  "https://username:password@my.stash.repo/scm/lib/my-super-lib.git"
```

composer operations work just fine. But I dont't want store plaintext credentials.

Is there a way to make composer ask username and password each time?

Repository is Atlassian Stash with https nginx in front of it (both https and http were tested)

`Composer version 70a20ebcc19f1ea8ab0954a4fbdce208b30085e7 2014-03-12 16:07:58`

**EDIT:**

For now I perform `git clone --mirror` by myself to populate composer's cache and then I just run composer install or composer update as usual (but It says it cannot update package info sometimes)

[code](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Repository/Vcs/GitDriver.php):

```
            $command = sprintf('git clone --mirror %s %s', escapeshellarg($this->url), escapeshellarg($this->repoDir));
            if (0 !== $this->process->execute($command, $output)) {
                $output = $this->process->getErrorOutput();

                if (0 !== $this->process->execute('git --version', $ignoredOutput)) {
                    throw new \RuntimeException('Failed to clone '.$this->url.', git was not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.' . "\n\n" . $this->process->getErrorOutput());
                }

                throw new \RuntimeException('Failed to clone '.$this->url.', could not read packages from it' . "\n\n" .$output);
            }
```

manual `git clone --mirror` works just fine and asks for my credentials. But composer (which obviously executes the same command) - it does not.

**EDIT2**

It seems to be PHP Storm 8 EAP problem which i'm using. Latest stable version requires authentication correctly during `composer install`, but not during `composer update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in latest PhpStorm 8 EAP 134.1456. PhpStorm 7.1.3 works with composer like command line (identical behavior) and performs `composer install` fine (but not `composer update`, but command line fails this too).

I'have submitted a [bugreport](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22543)

**EDIT**

My bugreport to composer has been replaced by [this](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2826)

**UPD2**

For now question is totally not actual. Composer handles authentication correctly and also asks to store credentials in `COMPOSER_HOME/auth.json`

Comment: More specific than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

You could setup an encrypted file with those http credential, in order for git to use them from that encrypted file.
That supposes a running gpg agent able t provide the unique password needed to access that credentials gpg-encrypted file.

The url you would use would then be:

```
https://username@my.stash.repo/scm/lib/my-super-lib.git
```

That allows git to ask to its [credential helper](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) for the right password (the one for '`username`').

See "[Is there a way to skip password typing when using `https://github`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309)" for a concrete example.

Comment: This leads to unnecessary difficulties with using composer. Each machine (or even user) who wants to use my private repository will have to perform these operation (and thus obviously I don't want to store even username in composer.json). It will be easier to manually clone all dependencies and setup autoloader, which kills all composer features. I hope there is easier way

Comment: @ScayTrase I agree. This is for a centralized access (where only *one* user has to enter his/her credentials, or, in my answer, the gpg key (once per session, not every time). That would be the case if all users could access to a single cloned repo and run the composer from there. But that might not be possible in your case.